# Помогите понять алгоритм

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Задача:

> В некоторой школе решили набрать три новых класса и оборудовать кабинеты для них новыми партами. За каждой партой может сидеть два учащихся. Известно количество учащихся в каждом из трех классов. Выведите наименьшее число парт, которое нужно приобрести для них.
>
> Входные данные:
> Программа получает на вход три натуральных числа: количество учащихся в каждом из трех классов.
>
> Выходные данные:
> Выведите ответ на задачу.

Вот как я решил:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int CLASSES = 3, NUMBER_OF_SEATS = 2;
    int students[CLASSES];
    float result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < CLASSES; i++){
        cin >> students[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < CLASSES; i++){
        result += students[i];
    }
    result = ceil(result / NUMBER_OF_SEATS);

    cout << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Но сайт на котором я решаю задачи выдает 4 ошибки из 10 тестов, в чем ошибка? Я не прошу выложить готовый код можно просто алгоритм

Comment: Сдаётся мне, что если в каждом из двух классов по 3 ученика, то нужны 4 парты, а не 3.

Comment: Алгоритм простейший; если a/2 с остатком - Int(a/2)+1 или a/2+0.5. Повторить для b и  c. Суммировать три значения.

Comment: На будущее: если у вас есть тесты к заданию -- их лучше прикреплять к своему вопросу, это позволяет быстрее разобраться.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы делал так:

```
const int CLASSES = 3, NUMBER_OF_SEATS = 2;

int result = 0, stds;

for (int i = 0; i < CLASSES; i++){
    cin >> stds;
    results += (stds+1)/NUMBER_OF_SEATS;
}
cout << result << endl;
```

И никаких `float`!

Answer (score 2):

Суть задачи - посчитать количество парт, ты же считаешь количество учащихся делить на 2, что не есть правильно. В конце то может оказаться 1 "стоячий" ученик

Логичнее было бы: поделить число учащихся в одном классе на 2, и если остаток от деления больше 0 (5\2 = 2 + 1 в остатке)(функция 5%2 выдаст 1), +1 к кол-ву парт на аудиторию.

```
if(StudentsInClassNmb1 % NUMBER_OF_SEATS > 0 ){
int result 1= StudentsInClassNmb1/NUMBER_OF_SEATS;
}else{int result1= (StudentsInClassNmb1/NUMBER_OF_SEATS)+1;}
```

Проделать( в общем ) 3 раза и вуаля - решено, останется только сложить

Answer (score 2):

Алгоритм следующий:

количество_парт = (ученики_класс_1 + 1) / 2 + (ученики_класс_2 + 1) / 2 + (ученики_класс_3 + 1) / 2

Деление целочисленное.